# XPATH - how to search for two different classes using an OR statement/whichever comes first

Tags: xpath

I am crawling 3 URLs of **different** webpages but want the results to go in the same field. The 3 webpages use different date mark up, example:

```
<div id="date_65"/>
<div class="date_today"/>
<div id="date_now"/>
```

Is there any way I can create some kind of 'OR' statement in XPATH to handle these variances.

Also, is it possible to make XPATH only grab the first one it sees and ignore any others?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which Xpath are you using? 1.0 or 2.0? The last version has an OR.

Comment: @Luixv so does the earlier version...

Comment: @Ian. OK. I didn't know. I should say then that "at least the last version has an OR" :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
(//div[starts-with(@id, 'date_') or starts-with(@class, 'date_')])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match a lot of different and possibly unknown elements, go with Ian Roberts' solution. If it's only about those three (or you don't want to match prefixes anyway), go for this:

```
//div[@id="date_65" or @class="date_today" or @id="date_now"]
```

If you've got support for XPath 2.0, you could also use it's set semantics of the comparison operators (there is one element in each set):

```
//div[(@id, @class) = ("date_today", "date_now", "date_65")].
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I used pipes and it seemed to do the job nicely. e.g. separated queries with this: "|"

Comment: Pipes will probably require the document to be scanned multiple times, resulting in poor performance (for large documents). Also, they disorder the result. If this is not of concern, the solution is fine, too.